# react js Formik <Form/> resetForm() is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I'm trying to reset the inputs in my formik Form on submit. It seems I'm supposed to use resetForm() to do that but i get the error:

src\components\CommentSubmition\inCommentSubmition.js
Line 19:13:  'resetForm' is not defined  no-undef

Here's my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import {createComment} from '../../services/CommentLocalStorage.js'
import * as Yup from 'yup';
 
function CommentForm(props){
   return (
        <Formik
        initialValues={{ autor: '', content: ''}}
        validationSchema={Yup.object({
            autor: Yup.string().required('Required'),
            content: Yup.string().required('Required')
        })}
        onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                createComment(props.pageEnum, props.articleId, values.autor, values.content)
                setSubmitting(false);
            },400);
            resetForm();
        }}
        >
            <Form>
                <label htmlFor="autor">Nome</label>
                <Field name="autor" type="autor" placeholder="Nome"/>
                <ErrorMessage name="autor" />
                <br/>
                <label htmlFor="content">Comentário</label>
                <Field name="content" type="content" placeholder="Comentário" />
                <ErrorMessage name="content" />
                <br/>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </Form>
        </Formik>
   );
 };

 export default CommentForm;
```

It seems most people make something like this:

```
const formik = some configuration
```

And then they use it like

```
formik.resetForm()
```

And instead I'm using the Formik component with all the stuff inside it (I did it based on an example available on the official tutorials). If possible i'd like to keep it like that and still make the form reset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass `resetForm` as a parameter to your `onSubmit` function. That should give your function access to the `resetForm` method from Formik thereby getting rid of the error and successfully reset the form. If you want to use any methods from the formik library inside your `onSubmit` function, first pass a parameter to the function so you can have access to the formik method. Let me know if this helps

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import {createComment} from '../../services/CommentLocalStorage.js'
import * as Yup from 'yup';
 
 
 
function CommentForm(props){
   return (
        <Formik
        initialValues={{ autor: '', content: ''}}
        validationSchema={Yup.object({
            autor: Yup.string().required('Required'),
            content: Yup.string().required('Required')
        })}
        onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, {resetForm }) => {  //<--- See here for code added
            setTimeout(() => {
                createComment(props.pageEnum, props.articleId, values.autor, values.content)
                setSubmitting(false);
            },400);
            resetForm();
        }}
        >
            <Form>
                <label htmlFor="autor">Nome</label>
                <Field name="autor" type="autor" placeholder="Nome"/>
                <ErrorMessage name="autor" />
                <br/>
                <label htmlFor="content">Comentário</label>
                <Field name="content" type="content" placeholder="Comentário" />
                <ErrorMessage name="content" />
                <br/>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </Form>
        </Formik>
   );
 };

 export default CommentForm;
```